# Como pegar todos os elementos pai com exceção de alguns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estou numa situação em que preciso pegar todos os "elementos pai" de uma div, mas **não posso pegar todos**, porque não iria resolver meu problema. Gostaria de saber se posso colocar um limite na obtenção desses elementos. Com um exemplo fica mais claro. Considerem a estrutura:

```
<div class="all">
    <div class="1">
        <div class="2">
            <div class="3">
                <div class="4">
                <!-- Conteúdo -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Nesse caso gostaria de pegar todos os elementos pai da div com a classe `4`, com exceção da div de classe `all` mas também quero todas as que estiverem acima da `.all`. É possível fazer isso via jquery?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Com a função [parents()](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) é simples, basta colocar dentro da função [not()](https://api.jquery.com/not/) aqueles elementos que não quer:

```js
var pais = $('.4').parents().not('.all, body, html');
pais.each(function() {
  console.log('classe do pai ' +$(this).prop("tagName")+ ': ' +$(this).prop('class'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="my-section">
    <div class="0">
        <div class="all">
            <div class="1">
                <div class="2">
                    <div class="3">
                        <div class="4">
                        <!-- Conteúdo -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 4):

Já tens uma resposta com jQuery, aqui fica uma com JavaScript nativo. Lembra-te que em HTML as classes não podem começar por números, penso que tenhas dado números só para o exemplo mas deixo o aviso na mesma.

```js
var getParents = (function() {
    function hasClass(el, classes) {
        var elClassList = [].slice.call(el.classList);
        return elClassList.filter(function(_class) {
            return classes.indexOf(_class) != -1;
        }).length != 0;
    }

    return function(from, not /*, not2, etc...*/ ) {
        var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
        var el = document.querySelector('.' + args.shift());
        var parents = [];
        while (el = el.parentElement) {
            if (el == document.body) break;
            if (!hasClass(el, args)) parents.push(el);
        }
        return parents;
    }
})();

console.log(getParents('c4', 'all')); // [div.c3, div.c2, div.c1]
```

```html
<div class="all">
    <div class="c1">
        <div class="c2">
            <div class="c3">
                <div class="c4">
                    <!-- Conteúdo -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiz este função que recebe como primeiro argumento a classe do elemento onde começa, e depois nos restantes argumentos as outras classes que **não queres apanhar**. Podes passar N argumentos.

Comment: @Miguel prefiro a minha maneira :) `notParent = document.querySelector(notParents[i]);` pesa muito no Browser

Comment: Pois realmente és muito mais javascript pro que eu. Se bem que que acho que a tua tem a desvantagem de os elementos '`not`' terem de ser classes `document.querySelector('.' + args.shift())`

Comment: Mas agora que penso tu também usas `...document.querySelector(...`, será que pesa mais por eu não especificar o tipo de seletor?

Comment: Uma versão com uma modificação pouco significativa: https://jsfiddle.net/ks8hu650/1/

Comment: @Miguel eu uso `document.querySelector` uma vez para ir buscar o ponto de partida, tu tinhas dentro do `while`, que pode correr muitas vezes.

Comment: Tens razão, tinha dentro do while e do for ainda por cima @Sergio

Comment: Mudei, https://jsfiddle.net/ks8hu650/2/ . Mais leve

Comment: @Miguel melhor sim, mas ainda assim estás a correr `.querySelector` dentro de um loop para todos os `notParents`.

Comment: Mas acho que é a melhor maneira para não me restringir só a classes/ids/tagname etc... Certo @Sergio?

Comment: @Miguel podes lançar uma pergunta a saber como fazer `$('.4').parents().not('.all, body, html');` em JS nativo :)

Comment: Feito e a desafiar-te um pouco mais @Sergio :P

Comment: @Miguel aceite :P