# Como obter os elementos pais com exceção de alguns em Js nativo

Tags: javascript

Digamos que tenho:

```
 <section id="ele-section1">
    <div data-section="1">
        <div class="not_this">
            <div>
                <div class="ele2">
                    <div id="ele3">
                        <div class="ele4">
                            <div class="child">
                                <!-- Conteúdo -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Quero 'agarrar' todos os elementos que sejam pais de `.ele4` exceto `.not_this` (também quero os acima deste).

Sei que com a ajuda de jQuery podia fazer-se assim:

```
$('.ele4').parents().not('.not_this, body, html');
```

Mas gostava de fazer esta funcionalidade somente em js nativo. Como fazer?

Comment: Fala Miguel! Da uma olhada nesse post de ontem aqui do stack, eu acredito que seja exatamente o que precisa :) http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/136834/como-pegar-todos-os-elementos-pai-com-exce%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-alguns Abraço!

Comment: @fperz a ideia desta pergunta [surgiu dessa](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/136834/como-pegar-todos-os-elementos-pai-com-exce%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-alguns#comment283723_136900) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes usar o [`Element.matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) que verifica se um elemento tem um certo seletor CSS, ou melhor se seria selecionado com um dado seletor CSS. Caso seja para usar em browsers antigos há um polyfill nesse link em cima para fazer uso da lógica do `.matches`.

Assim a funcão poderia ser assim:

```
var getParents = (function() {
    function match(el, classes) {
        return classes.filter(function(css) {
            return el.matches(css);
        }).length != 0;
    }

    return function(from, not /*, not2, etc...*/ ) {
        var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
        var el = document.querySelector(args.shift());
        var parents = [];
        while (el = el.parentElement) {
            if (!match(el, args)) parents.push(el);
        }
        return parents;
    }
})();

console.log(getParents('.ele4', '.not_this', '#teste', 'body', 'html')); 
// dá [div#ele3, div.ele2, div, div, section#ele-section1]
```

E nessa seleção ficam de fora elemento(s) com classe `not_this` e também a id `teste`, para além do `body` e do `html`

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4n4od3a8/

Comment: Excelente @Sergio Obrigado. Não conhecia. Testei também para não ir buscar `'[data-section="1"]'` e funciona bem

Comment: Não ligues a isto, é só para pôr esta pergunta nos fav e ter aqui uma solução adaptada com o teu codigo como alternativa. https://jsfiddle.net/ks8hu650/11/